# flutter_tex package TeXViewDocument text line breaking issue

Tags: flutter, flutter-tex

I'm working on a quiz app and I have rendered a text with html and mathjax.But when I render the text it keeps line breaking.Even though there is space to fit the text it keeps line breaking.Is there a solution for that?